# How to get column title for each row entry

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am using a row id to obtain the cells for a single row. However, the response returns the column id but not the title of the column. In an attempt to make the code readable for others it would be helpful to also obtain the column title. I was thinking of doing this by using the column id that is obtained in the getRow function but I am not entirely sure how to catch it. Below is the basic getRow function for reference. I appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance all.

```
smartsheet.sheets.getRow(options)
  .then(function(row) {
  console.log(row);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a separate answer based on your response (and for easier formatting).

I have a couple specific recommendations that will help you.

1. Try to consolidate your API calls.

   > I then want to use that columnID to call getColumns(columnId) to obtain the title.

This is 'work' that you don't need to do. A single `GET /sheets/{sheetId}` will include all the data you need in one call. It's just a matter of parsing the JSON response.

2. Use this as an opportunity to improve your ability to work with JSON.

   > I do not know how to catch the columnId once getRow() is called.

The response is a single object with nested arrays and objects. Learning to navigate the JSON in a way that makes sense to you will come in really handy.

I would recommend saving the response from a GET sheet call as it's own JSON file. From there, you can bring it into your script and play with your logic to reference the values you want.

Comment: I get what you're saying now. I've got a script working so thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of addressing this is to dynamically create a column map on my first `GET /sheets/{sheetId}` request.
Let's say we have a sheet with three columns: Japan, Cat, and Cafe. Here is one way to make a column map.

```
const columnMap = makeColumnMap(<your sheet data>);

function makeColumnMap(sheetData){
    const colMap = {};
    sheetData.columns.map( column => colMap[column.title] = column.id);
    return colMap;
}
```

Now, you can reference your specific columns like this: `columnMap["Japan"]`, `columnMap["Cat"]`, and `columnMap["Cafe"]` or you can use dot notation if you prefer.

Basically, what we're doing is creating a dictionary to map the column titles to the corresponding column id.

Comment: Taylor's idea of the ColumnMap is a sound idea. However, if you don't want to pull down the entire sheet, just to get the column titles, you can also just grab the columns with a call to smartsheet.sheets.getColumns(). Documented here: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#list-columns

Comment: This gets me the columns but what I really need it to obtain the row with the column titles. So I obtain a row and for each entry I get the value plus the columnID. I then want to use that columnID to call getColumns(columnId) to obtain the title. I want to repeat this for each entry of the row so the json response contains the title of the column for each row value so I know what the value corresponds to. My issue is I do not know how to catch the columnId once getRow() is called.